# My app crashes when I click on the button to go to the second activity (checklist) but works perfectly fine on its own

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a supermarket multi-purpose app to provide users with a built-in checklist, item locator, and a promotions display.

My checklist works fine on its own, but when I try to put it into my multi-purpose app and access it. It crashes with the error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication2/com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity5}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference".

I've tried declaring actions in the manifest and to use different OnClickButton codes but to no avail.

I'm new to programming so please do not hesitate to tell me if I have not provided a necessary code and thank you for helping me in advance. :)

Main Activity (consists of a starting screen with four buttons)

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication2;
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity1::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)

        }


        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity4::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)

            val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
            button.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity5::class.java)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
        android:text="@string/locator"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.736"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
        android:text="@string/checklist"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.276"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
        android:text="@string/promotions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.237"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:background="@drawable/checklist"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.223"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:background="@drawable/magnifying"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.776"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.345"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:background="@drawable/promotion2"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.223"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.345"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pricetag"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.776"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
        android:text="@string/price_list"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.76"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity5 (checklist)

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main5.*

class MainActivity5 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val itemlist = arrayListOf<String>()
        val adapter =ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice
            , itemlist)
        add.setOnClickListener {

            itemlist.add(editText.text.toString())
            listView.adapter =  adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            editText.text.clear()
        }
        clear.setOnClickListener {

            itemlist.clear()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "You Selected the item --> "+itemlist.get(i), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        delete.setOnClickListener {
            val position: SparseBooleanArray = listView.checkedItemPositions
            val count = listView.count
            var item = count - 1
            while (item >= 0) {
                if (position.get(item))
                {
                    adapter.remove(itemlist.get(item))
                }
                item--
            }
            position.clear()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity5 xml

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_an_item"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="@string/my_shopping_list"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest XML

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity4" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity3" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity5"
            android:label="Checklist">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication2, PID: 11150
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication2/com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity5}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity5.onCreate(MainActivity5.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
            button.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity5::class.java)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

outside of the lambda of the button3 to see if it work. The error message mean that you have invoke a method on a null Button variable. Can you tell us what line does the error happened?

Comment: I have moved it outside but it did not work. Also there is no specific line that the error happens I just get a really long error message.

Comment: add.setOnClickListener {
           ...
        }
it said this line caused the error. Make sure you have initialized the "add" variable.

Comment: How do you initialize add?

Comment: try
val add = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add) 
and then set the ClickListener to it.

Comment: val add = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add)
        add.setOnClickListener {

            itemlist.add(editText.text.toString())
            listView.adapter =  adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            editText.text.clear()  Still doesn't work

Comment: this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in Activity5.kt, you must set contentView of R.layout.activity5

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks. But thank you so much for being so generous with helping me and also being so patient. Stay safe and thank you!